# Cordova / Phonegap app (lots of images) dealing with memory warnings

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, memory, ionic-framework

I am trying to wrap my website into an app that I made with AngularJS.
I got a website with lots of "cards" divs, and each of them hv an image on them.

you can find the link here: [cow.aforadrian.com](http://cow.aforadrian.com)

[screenshot of what i did in the web version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGohI.jpg)

each page will hv about 100 "cards" with each unique image, loading from local JSON file. It went well in the browser

I package all the images locally into an app.
It worked all good on iOS simulator and even on my new iPad Air.
But then I realise it wont work in other devices with lesser memories.
It averagely took up to 260MB ram... and sometimes go way up to 500MB...

I tried to disable all css visual or transformation effects but it didnt help much.

At first I thought it was the size of the images, but I hv checked and try using small thumbnail to test, the memory issue still persists.

so I guess it had to do with how the screen handles the rendering of this amount of images.

I m not very good with angularjs and barely get this site up and running. it got me scratching my head on how to fix this. I never worked with an app before so the memory issue really didnt occur to me and i dun hv a concept of how to deal with this.

Other threads hv talked about similar issues on creating image carousel, that one should lazyload the image before and destroy the image after. Yet I am not sure if this is the right approach for me, and I am not sure how to achieve this.

UPDATE:
I am using ng-repeat to load image links pointing to a local image folder.
Is this the reason why it is using up a lot of RAM/Memory? are there better way to achieve this? will it help if i revamp the website in ionic framework instead of pure Angularjs + Cordova?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's quite hard to help you without seeing your implementation, maybe you can share the correspondig lines of code. Assuming you are using a ng-repeat to render your cards, a [collection repeat](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/) might be what you're looking for. Further info [here](http://blog.ionic.io/collection-repeat-iteration-two/).

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention, i was using a simple ng-repeat to loop through the json file(with image links pointing to a an image folder). I however was not using ionic. I was thinking to revamp the site using ionic framework instead of pure Angular JS. However before this I would like to know if using ioninc could solve the memory/ram problem... becuz ionic basically is an addon of Angularjs so I m afraid the same problem will persist...

Comment: The ionic tag is a bit missleading in this case ;) Other UI frameworks offer similar concepts see the [virtual repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) in angular material f.e. I'm afraid it'll boil down to trying it out, I guess noone here can predict the performance without seeing the actual code & data.